Gravel under concrete in Second Floor Bathroom
I'm having my bathroom redone on the second floor of the house and the contractor replaced the concrete slab under the tiles with concrete over gravel. On the second floor? Is that to code? Is that even safe? Do I need to contact my insurance company/public adjustor?
I'm in Pennsylvania.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is the rest of the 2nd floor concrete slab?

It seems odd, but maybe they did it so the concrete did not stick to the floor to make removing/cutting(for repairs of pipes) easier in the future.  Your local building department can tell you if it is allowed or not.
